# HowTo for installing Informix ClientSDK on OpenSuSE 11.2

Tags: sdk, client, installation, informix, opensuse

Is there a simple tutorial or HowTo that describes the installation of the IBM Informix ClientSDK on OpenSuSE 11.2? I was not able to get it work.... I set all the system environment variables like INFORMIXDIR, encoding vars, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: it seems that you use SO, but not comment, vote nor accept answers. Have a look at your older questions, check answers, comment when they were helpful or not and accept some responses.

Comment: Is your problem with the installation of CSDK or with using it after you've successfully installed it?  Is your problem connecting to an IDS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have problems with installing client or with connecting database?

In `clientsdk.3.70.UC1.LINUX.tar` there is `client_install_guide.pdf`. If you have any problems then try describe it: show us error message, trace log, environment etc.

PS With installing newest, 3.70UC1 version I had problem problem on one of my old Debian machine, but it installed without problems on Ubuntu-server 9.10.